# JSP included header element hide before the page load

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a simple `login.jsp` page with login forms.
The header and footer is included, the `pageheader.jsp` contain the header body tag etc.
I would like to hide the header and footer class in the included jsp, but only in the login page, before the page loading.

I thought it simple and it is working, but hide the header after the page is loaded.
I think it is not to complicate but I'm a beginner in this area.
Anyone could help me with this? Thanks!

```
<jsp:include page="pageheader.jsp"/>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#wp-header").hide();

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to decide whether to show the header on the server side rather than on the client side. You'd need to modify pageheader.jsp to conditionally write the element with id `wp-header`.

```
<c:if test="${hideHeaderFooter ne 'true'}">
    <div id="wp-header">
        <!-- your header -->
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Then in your login.jsp, set the `hideHeaderFooter` request attribute before including pageheader.jsp.

```
<c:set var="hideHeaderFooter" value="true" scope="request"/>
<jsp:include page="pageheader.jsp"/>
<%-- No need to hide #wp-header with javascript--%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it, but unfortunately not working. The header is always visible now (such as in Opera), but with IE absolutely break the design of the page. Previously tried other solutions and if i wrote something before the pagehaeder include then the page is broke (just with IE)